# How do I increase the font size of the email in Geary?

Tags: fonts, size, geary

It doesn't seem possible to change the font size of the email **automatically** (Ctrl+Scroll seems to be the only solution and it is manual) and the text on my laptop screen is too small.

Is there a way to modify this without affecting the rest of Gnome?